# How do I add information to an exception message in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, exception

How do I add information to an exception message without changing its class in ruby?

The approach I'm currently using is

```
strings.each_with_index do |string, i|
  begin
    do_risky_operation(string)
  rescue
    raise $!.class, "Problem with string number #{i}: #{$!}"
  end
end
```

Ideally, I would also like to preserve the backtrace.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

To reraise the exception and modify the message, while preserving the exception class and its backtrace, simply do:

```
strings.each_with_index do |string, i|
  begin
    do_risky_operation(string)
  rescue Exception => e
    raise $!, "Problem with string number #{i}: #{$!}", $!.backtrace
  end
end
```

Which will yield:

```
# RuntimeError: Problem with string number 0: Original error message here
#     backtrace...
```

Comment: On the line beginning with `raise`, is there a reason to use `$!` instead of `e`? They're the same object.

Comment: @Jordan `e === $!` so yes you could use `e` instead of `$1`, assuming `e` is defined. The advantage of `$!` is that it is always available in an Exception block. Also of note is that `$@ === e.backtrace`.

Comment: You can also use `e2 = e.class.new "Foo: #{e}"` to create a new exception of the same type, and then `e2.set_backtrace(e.backtrace)` to take the backtrace from the original exception.

Comment: wish I could give a +++ for this answer as I learned a lot from it (and the follow up comments)

Comment: Note that rescuing `Exception` is probably not what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048173/why-is-it-bad-style-to-rescue-exception-e-in-ruby.

Comment: Also note that `$!` is a _global variable_ pointing to the last exception raised in running Ruby program. It could be overwritten during the rescue block by another exception being raised in another thread. That is one reason to prefer using `e`.

Comment: @mlovic In this case, where the Exception immediately gets re-raised, it _is_ probably what you want.

Comment: At some point, the code that prints the exception to STDERR for an exception that isn't caught now prints out the previous exception as well.  All the methods on this page raise a new exception and thus the print out now has two stacks.  I've yet to see a way to raise the same exception with an appended message.

Answer (score 20):

It's not much better, but you can just reraise the exception with a new message:

```
raise $!, "Problem with string number #{i}: #{$!}"
```

You can also get a modified exception object yourself with the `exception` method:

```
new_exception = $!.exception "Problem with string number #{i}: #{$!}"
raise new_exception
```

Comment: The first snippet is what I'm after. Looking at the documentation for `Kernel#raise`, it says that if you have more than one argument, the first item can be either an `Exception` class, or an object that returns an exception when `.exception` is called. I think my brain has just had an exception.

Comment: but wouldn't this nix the original message? Wouldn't @Mark Rushakoff's approach be more conservative?

Comment: @yar: No, this doesn't nix the original message. That's the entire purpose of the `#{$!}` interpolation. It would nix the original message if you left that out, just like if you left out the call to `super` in Mark's method. I would frankly say my way is more conservative, since it's just using the language's intended exception re-raising mechanisms, whereas Mark's solution involves creating a whole module and redefining the `message` method just to get the same effect.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the explanation, that's actually quite cool. I didn't realize that `raise` can take more than one param... I should've guessed that re-raising errors was already contemplated in Ruby, as it is a necessary thing.

Comment: Note that this will alter the backtrace, unless `$!.backtrace` is passed as the 3rd argument

Answer (score 15):

I realize I'm 6 years late to this party, but...I thought I understood Ruby error handling until this week and ran across this question.  While the answers are useful, there is non-obvious (and undocumented) behavior that may be useful to future readers of this thread.  All code was run under ruby v2.3.1.

[@Andrew Grimm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38765/andrew-grimm) [asks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823748/how-do-i-add-information-to-an-exception-message-in-ruby)

> How do I add information to an exception message without changing its class in ruby?

and then provides sample code:

```rb
raise $!.class, "Problem with string number #{i}: #{$!}"
```

I think it is *critical* to point out that this does NOT add information **to the original error instance object**, but instead raises a NEW error object with the same class.

@BoosterStage says

> To reraise the exception and modify the message...

but again, the provided code

```rb
raise $!, "Problem with string number #{i}: #{$!}", $!.backtrace
```

will raise a new instance of whatever error class is referenced by `$!`, but it will *not* be the exact same instance as `$!`.

The difference between [@Andrew Grimm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38765/andrew-grimm)'s code and @BoosterStage's example is the fact that the first argument to `#raise` in the first case is a `Class`, whereas in the second case it is an instance of some (presumably) `StandardError`.  The difference matters because the documentation for [Kernel#raise](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) says:

> With a single String argument, raises a RuntimeError with the string as a message. Otherwise, the first parameter should be the name of an Exception class (or an object that returns an Exception object when sent an exception message).

If only one argument is given and it is an error object instance, *that object will be `raise`d* **IF** that object's `#exception` method inherits or implements the default behavior defined in [Exception#exception(string)](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Exception.html#method-i-exception):

> With no argument, or if the argument is the same as the receiver, return the receiver. Otherwise, create a new exception object of the same class as the receiver, but with a message equal to string.to_str.

As many would guess:

```rb
catch StandardError => e
  raise $!
```

raises the same error referenced by $!, the same as simply calling:

```rb
catch StandardError => e
  raise
```

but probably not for the reasons one might think.  In this case, the call to `raise` is *NOT* just raising the object in `$!`...it raises the result of `$!.exception(nil)`, which in this case happens to be `$!`.

To clarify this behavior, consider this toy code:

```rb
class TestError < StandardError
    def initialize(message=nil)
        puts 'initialize'
        super
    end
    def exception(message=nil)
        puts 'exception'
        return self if message.nil? || message == self
        super
    end
end
```

Running it (this is the same as [@Andrew Grimm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38765/andrew-grimm)'s sample which I quoted above):

```rb
2.3.1 :071 > begin ; raise TestError, 'message' ; rescue => e ; puts e ; end
```

results in:

```
initialize
message
```

So a TestError was initialized, rescued, and had its message printed.  So far so good.  A second test (analogous to @BoosterStage's sample quoted above):

```rb
2.3.1 :073 > begin ; raise TestError.new('foo'), 'bar' ; rescue => e ; puts e ; end
```

The somewhat surprising results:

```
initialize
exception
bar
```

So a `TestError` was initialized with 'foo', but then `#raise` has called `#exception` on the first argument (an instance of `TestError`) and passed in the message of 'bar' *to create a second instance of `TestError`, which is what ultimately gets raised*.

TIL.

Also, like [@Sim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/622495/sim), I am *very* concerned about preserving any original backtrace context, but instead of implementing a custom error handler like his `raise_with_new_message`, Ruby's `Exception#cause` has my back: whenever I want to catch an error, wrap it in a domain-specific error and then raise *that* error, I still have the original backtrace available via `#cause` on the domain-specific error being raised.

The point of all this is that--like [@Andrew Grimm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38765/andrew-grimm)--I want to raise errors with more context; specifically, I want to only raise domain-specific errors from certain points in my app that can have many network-related failure modes.  Then my error reporting can be made to handle the domain errors at the top level of my app and I have all the context I need for logging/reporting by calling `#cause` recursively until I get to the "root cause".

I use something like this:

```rb
class BaseDomainError < StandardError
  attr_reader :extra
  def initialize(message = nil, extra = nil)
    super(message)
    @extra = extra
  end
end
class ServerDomainError < BaseDomainError; end
```

Then if I am using something like Faraday to make calls to a remote REST service, I can wrap all possible errors into a domain-specific error and pass in extra info (which I believe is the original question of this thread):

```rb
class ServiceX
  def initialize(foo)
    @foo = foo
  end
  def get_data(args)
    begin
      # This method is not defined and calling it will raise an error
      make_network_call_to_service_x(args)
    rescue StandardError => e
      raise ServerDomainError.new('error calling service x', binding)
    end
  end
end
```

Yeah, that's right: I literally just realized I can set the `extra` info to the current `binding` to grab all local vars defined at the time the `ServerDomainError` is instantiated/raised.  This test code:

```rb
begin
  ServiceX.new(:bar).get_data(a: 1, b: 2)
rescue
  puts $!.extra.receiver
  puts $!.extra.local_variables.join(', ')
  puts $!.extra.local_variable_get(:args)
  puts $!.extra.local_variable_get(:e)
  puts eval('self.instance_variables', $!.extra)
  puts eval('self.instance_variable_get(:@foo)', $!.extra)
end
```

will output:

```
#<ServiceX:0x00007f9b10c9ef48>
args, e
{:a=>1, :b=>2}
undefined method `make_network_call_to_service_x' for #<ServiceX:0x00007f9b10c9ef48 @foo=:bar>
@foo
bar
```

Now a Rails controller calling ServiceX doesn't particularly need to know that ServiceX is using [Faraday](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday/tree/master/lib/faraday) (or gRPC, or anything else), it just makes the call and handles `BaseDomainError`.  Again: for logging purposes, a single handler at the top level can recursively log all the `#cause`s of any caught errors, and for any `BaseDomainError` instances in the error chain it can also log the `extra` values, potentially including the local variables pulled from the encapsulated `binding`(s).

I hope this tour has been as useful for others as it was for me.  I learned a lot.

UPDATE: [Skiptrace](https://github.com/gsamokovarov/skiptrace) looks like it adds the bindings to Ruby errors.

Also, see [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56384868/5299483) for info about how the implementation of  `Exception#exception` will **clone** the object (copying instance variables).

Comment: At some point, the print out of an uncaught exception now prints out the previous exception as well.  As you say, the various choices are creating and raising a new exception and thus, the output has two stacks.  I've yet to find a way to raise the same exception with a modified message.

Answer (score 5):

Here's another way:

```
class Exception
  def with_extra_message extra
    exception "#{message} - #{extra}"
  end
end

begin
  1/0
rescue => e
  raise e.with_extra_message "you fool"
end

# raises an exception "ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0 - you fool" with original backtrace
```

(revised to use the `exception` method internally, thanks @Chuck)

Answer (score 4):

My approach would be to `extend` the `rescue`d error with an anonymous module that extends the error's `message` method:

```
def make_extended_message(msg)
    Module.new do
      @@msg = msg
      def message
        super + @@msg
      end
    end
end

begin
  begin
      raise "this is a test"
  rescue
      raise($!.extend(make_extended_message(" that has been extended")))
  end
rescue
    puts $! # just says "this is a test"
    puts $!.message # says extended message
end
```

That way, you don't clobber any other information in the exception (i.e. its `backtrace`).

Comment: For those curious, if an exception occurs in `message`, you don't get a Stack Overflow, but if you were to do so in `Exception#initialize`, you do.

Comment: And thanks to Ruby being dynamic yet strongly typed, it's easy to get an Exception in the `message` method. Just try to add a String and number together :)

Comment: @yar: Easily worked around by doing `super + String(@@msg)` or equivalent.

Comment: To be just a bit polemic, your first instinct was not to do that. And you probably wouldn't think of that in your unit tests either (the holy grail of dynamic langs). So someday it would blow up at runtime, and THEN you'd add that safeguard.

Comment: I'm not JUST complaining about dynamic langs: I'm also thinking about how to defensively program in them.

Comment: As another example of the hazards of dynamic-yet-strong typing, this will also fail if the exception did not already have a message, because NilClass doesn't define the `+` operator. It would probably be better in a lot of ways to use interpolation — `def message() "#{super} #{@@msg}" end`.

Comment: Hmm, this is strange (and unfortunate). It seems that overridding message does not have any affect on the exception's other methods such as `to_s` and `inspect`. For example: `begin; 0/0; rescue; puts $!.extend(Module.new do; def message; super + ' With additional info!'; end; end).inspect; end
#<ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0> `  (I would have expected that `inspect` would have been defined in terms of message, such as `def inspect; "<#{self.class}: #{message}"; end`. Am I incorrect?)

Comment: Ah, I see. `message` is actually defined in terms of `to_s` (not the other way around): `return rb_funcall(exc, rb_intern("to_s"), 0, 0);`

Answer (score 3):

Most of these answers are incredibly convoluted. Maybe they were necessary in Ruby 1.8 or whatever, but in modern versions* this is totally straightforward and intuitive. Just `rescue => e`, append to `e.message`, and `raise`.

```rb
begin
  raise 'oops'
rescue => e
  e.message << 'y daisy'
  raise
end
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
        4: from /Users/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        3: from /Users/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/bin/irb:23:in `load'
        2: from /Users/david/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/irb-1.2.6/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        1: from (irb):2
RuntimeError (oopsy daisy)
```

---

* I've only tested with 2.7.2 and 3.1.2, but I assume everything in between is covered, and probably some earlier versions of 2.x as well.

Comment: What about adding message to `ZeroDivisionError` for example?

Comment: @mechnicov The above pattern works fine for me with ZDE in Ruby 3.1.2 for macOS -- just replace `raise 'oops'` with `puts 1 / 0`, and you get `(irb):46:in \`/': divided by 0ydaisy (ZeroDivisionError)`

Answer (score 2):

I put my vote that [Ryan Heneise's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155826/ryan-heneise) answer should be the accepted one.

This is a common problem in complex applications and preserving the original backtrace is often critical so much so that we have a utility method in our `ErrorHandling` helper module for this.

One of the problems we discovered was that sometimes trying to generate more meaningful messages when a system is in a messed up state would result in exceptions being generated inside the exception handler itself which led us to harden our utility function as follows:

```ruby
def raise_with_new_message(*args)
  ex = args.first.kind_of?(Exception) ? args.shift : $!
  msg = begin
    sprintf args.shift, *args
  rescue Exception => e
    "internal error modifying exception message for #{ex}: #{e}"
  end
  raise ex, msg, ex.backtrace
end
```

When things go well

```ruby
begin
  1/0
rescue => e
  raise_with_new_message "error dividing %d by %d: %s", 1, 0, e
end
```

you get a nicely modified message

```
ZeroDivisionError: error dividing 1 by 0: divided by 0
    from (irb):19:in `/'
    from (irb):19
    from /Users/sim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

When things go badly

```ruby
begin
  1/0
rescue => e
  # Oops, not passing enough arguments here...
  raise_with_new_message "error dividing %d by %d: %s", e
end
```

you still don't lose track of the big picture

```
ZeroDivisionError: internal error modifying exception message for divided by 0: can't convert ZeroDivisionError into Integer
    from (irb):25:in `/'
    from (irb):25
    from /Users/sim/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Why are you rescuing from the `Exception` class, rather than `StandardError`?

Comment: @AndrewGrimm rescuing `StandardError` does not cover the kinds of edge cases that tend to occur with greater frequency when the proverbial hits the fan. Good examples are `LoadError` and `NotImplementedError`. We've also had cases of `#to_s` causing stack overflows as they smartly try to produce meaningful messages in complex data structures. You just don't know what will happen.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I ended up doing:

```rb
Exception.class_eval do
  def prepend_message(message)
    mod = Module.new do
      define_method :to_s do
        message + super()
      end
    end
    self.extend mod
  end

  def append_message(message)
    mod = Module.new do
      define_method :to_s do
        super() + message
      end
    end
    self.extend mod
  end
end
```

Examples:

```
strings = %w[a b c]
strings.each_with_index do |string, i|
  begin
    do_risky_operation(string)
  rescue
    raise $!.prepend_message "Problem with string number #{i}:"
  end
end
=> NoMethodError: Problem with string number 0:undefined method `do_risky_operation' for main:Object
```

and:

```
pry(main)> exception = 0/0 rescue $!
=> #<ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0>
pry(main)> exception = exception.append_message('. With additional info!')
=> #<ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0. With additional info!>
pry(main)> exception.message
=> "divided by 0. With additional info!"
pry(main)> exception.to_s
=> "divided by 0. With additional info!"
pry(main)> exception.inspect
=> "#<ZeroDivisionError: divided by 0. With additional info!>"
```

This is similar to [Mark Rushakoff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2823807/47185)'s answer but:

1. Overrides `to_s` instead of `message` since by default `message` is defined as simply `to_s` (at least in Ruby 2.0 and 2.2 where I tested it)
2. Calls `extend` for you instead of making the caller do that extra step.
3. Uses `define_method` and a closure so that the local variable `message` can be referenced. When I tried using a class `variable @@message`, it warned, "warning: class variable access from toplevel" (See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8015535/ruby-dynamic-classes-how-to-fix-warning-class-variable-access-from-toplevel): "Since you're not creating a class with the class keyword, your class variable is being set on `Object`, not [your anonymous module]")

Features:

- Easy to use
- Reuses the same object (instead of creating a new instance of the class), so things like object identity, class, and backtrace are preserved
- `to_s`, `message`, and `inspect` all respond appropriately
- Can be used with an exception that is already stored in a variable; doesn't require you to re-raise anything (like the solution that involved passing the backtrace to raise: `raise $!, …, $!.backtrace`). This was important to me since the exception was passed in to my logging method, not something I had rescued myself.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to use [`:cause`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) key to prevent message duplication

> The `cause` of the generated exception (accessible via [`Exception#cause`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Exception.html#method-i-cause)) is automatically set to the "current" exception (`$!`), if any. An alternative value, either an `Exception` object or `nil`, can be specified via the `:cause` argument.

```rb
begin
  do_risky_operation
rescue => e
  raise e.class, "#{e.message} (some extra message)", e.backtrace, cause: nil
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Another approach would be to add context (extra information) about the exception as a *hash* instead of as a *string*.

Check out [this pull request](https://github.com/rubyworks/facets/pull/291) where I proposed adding a few new methods to make it really easy to add extra context information to exceptions, like this:

```rb
begin
  …
  User.find_each do |user|
    reraise_with_context(user: user) do
      send_reminder_email(user)
    end
  end
  …

rescue
  # $!.context[:user], etc. is available here
  report_error $!, $!.context
end
```

or even:

```rb
User.find_each.reraise_with_context do |user|
  send_reminder_email(user)
end
```

The nice thing about this approach is that it lets you add extra information in a very concise way. And it doesn't even require you to define new exception classes inside which to wrap the original exceptions.

As much as I like @Lemon Cat's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56371923/47185) for many reasons, and it's certainly appropriate for some cases, I feel like if what you are actually trying to do is attach additional information about the original exception, it seems preferable to just attach it directly to that exception it pertains to rather than inventing a new wrapper exception (and adding another layer of indirection).

Another example:

```rb
class ServiceX
  def get_data(args)
    reraise_with_context(StandardError, binding: binding, service: self.class, callee: __callee__) do
      # This method is not defined and calling it will raise an error
      make_network_call_to_service_x(args)
    end
  end
end
```

The downside of this approach is that you have to update your error handling to actually *use* the information that may be available in `exception.context`. But you would have to do that *anyway* in order to recursively call `cause` to get to the root excetion.