# Raise custom Exception with arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

I'm defining a custom Exception on a model in rails as kind of a wrapper Exception: (`begin[code]rescue[raise custom exception]end`)

When I raise the Exception, I'd like to pass it some info about a) the instance of the model whose internal functions raise the error, and b) the error that was caught.

This is going on an automated import method of a model that gets populated by POST request to from foreign datasource.

tldr; How can one pass arguments to an Exception, given that you define the Exception yourself? I have an initialize method on that Exception but the `raise` syntax seems to only accept an Exception class and message, no optional parameters that get passed into the instantiation process.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

## Solution:

```
class FooError < StandardError
  attr_reader :foo

  def initialize(foo)
   super
   @foo = foo
  end
end
```

This is the best way if you follow the [Rubocop Style Guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#exception-class-messages) and always pass your message as the second argument to `raise`:

```
raise FooError.new(foo), 'argh'
```

You can get `foo` like this:

```
rescue FooError => error
  error.foo     # => 1234
  error.message # => 'argh'
```

If you want to customize the error message then write:

```
class FooError < StandardError
  attr_reader :foo

  def initialize(foo)
   super
   @foo = foo
  end

  def message
    "The foo is: #{foo}"
  end
end
```

This works great if `foo` is required. If you want `foo` to be an optional argument, then keep reading.

---

### If you don't follow the Rubocop Style Guide

And want this to work:

```
raise FooError.new('argh', foo)
```

You need to pass the message to `super` as the only argument:

```
class FooError < StandardError
  attr_reader :foo

  def initialize(message, foo)
   super(message)
   @foo = foo
  end
end
```

---

## Explanation:

#### Pass your message as the second argument to `raise`

As the [Rubocop Style Guide](https://github.com/rubocop-hq/ruby-style-guide#exception-class-messages) says, the message and the exception should be passed separately. If you write:

```
raise FooError.new('argh')
```

And want to pass a backtrace, there is no way to do it without passing the message twice:

```
raise FooError.new('argh'), 'argh', other_error.backtrace
```

You need to pass a backtrace if you want to re-raise an exception as a new instance with the same backtrace and a different message or data. Sometimes this is very useful.

#### Why is this so complicated?

The crux of the problem is a design flaw in Ruby: exception messages get set in two different ways.

```
raise StandardError, 'argh'     # case 1
raise StandardError.new('argh') # case 2
```

In case 1, `raise` just calls `StandardError.new('argh')`, so these are the same. But what if you pass an exception instance and a message to `raise`?

```
raise FooError.new(foo), 'argh', backtrace
```

`raise` will set `'argh'` as the message on the `FooError` instance, so it behaves as if you called `super('argh')` in `FooError#initialize`.

We want to be able to use this syntax, because otherwise, we'll have to pass the message twice anytime we want to pass a backtrace:

```
raise FooError.new(foo, 'argh'), 'argh', backtrace
raise FooError.new('argh', foo), 'argh', backtrace
```

But what if `foo` is optional? Then `FooError#initialize` is overloaded.

```
raise FooError, 'argh'          # case A
raise FooError.new(foo), 'argh' # case B
```

In case A, `raise` will call `FooError.new('argh')`, but your code expects an optional `foo`, not a message. This is bad. What are your options?

1. accept that the value passed to `FooError#initialize` may be either `foo` or a message.
2. Don't use case A style. If you're not passing `foo`, write `raise FooError.new(), 'argh'`
3. Make foo a keyword argument

IMO, don't do 2. The code's not self-documenting, so you have to remember all of this. Too complicated.

If you don't want to use a keyword argument, my implementation of `FooError` way at the top of this answer actually works great with 1. This is why `FooError#initialize` has to call `super` and not `super()`. Because when you write `raise FooError, 'argh'`, `foo` will be `'argh'`, and you have to pass it to the parent class to set the message. The code doesn't break if you call `super` with something that isn't a string; nothing happens.

3 is the simplest option, if you're ok with a keyword argument - [h/t Lemon Cat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56384868/1067145). Here's the code for that:

```
class FooError < StandardError
  attr_reader :foo

  def initialize(message, foo: nil)
   super(message)
   @foo = foo
  end
end

raise FooError, 'message', backtrace
raise FooError(foo: foo), 'message', backtrace
```

Comment: i' m on the same kind of problem ,& when i do somthing like this @foo stays nil , and foo is in message like self.message inside a class FooError like custom error class ...
:`(

Comment: I think that in `SuperWithMessageError`, the `message` isn't set correctly because within the `initialize` method you are calling `super(message)` where `message` is `nil`, in which case `StandardError`'s behavior is to set the `message` value to the class name.  This explains why `_ex_.message` is 'SuperWithMessageError' in your example.  If you changed the call to `super` to be `super(foo)`, then the `message` would get set to whatever value of `foo` is provided.

Comment: @LemonCat that is all true but your solution isn't what the OP wants. To quote: "the raise syntax seems to only accept an Exception class and message, no optional parameters that get passed into the instantiation process." In other words, the OP is interested in an optional parameter that's not the message. Changing the call to `super(foo)` won't help because the goal is to have a parameter that's separate from the message.

Comment: @MaxWallace I follow you.  The point I was trying to make was that when I read "In the second case, in `SuperWithMessageError`...the `message` doesn't get set correctly" is misleading: the `message` doesn't get set correctly because it is never initialized within `#initialize(foo)`.  For more context, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/56371923/5299483.

Comment: @LemonCat your comment isn't correct. In `SuperWithMessageError` the message doesn't get set correctly because it's explicitly set to the wrong value (the return value of `message` before `super` is called, i.e. the class name) in `#initialize`. But what I think you are trying to get at, which is correct, is that in `SuperError#initialize` `foo` is implicitly passed in to `super`, which is why it works. I will update the answer and try to clarify that.

Comment: @MaxWallace, thanks for correcting my error.  My understanding from reading the docs was that `#message` gets set to the class name if a `message` value is not provided to `#initialize`, but as you correctly point out even in the `#initialize` method of an `Exception` subclass, `#message` will return the class name until `super(message)` is called to set (well, really to _override_) the default message.  TIL.

Comment: @LemonCat yeah, the docs on this could be much better. I also ended up reading the C source. Let me know if you think anything in my updated answer could be clearer!

Answer (score 81):

create an instance of your exception with new:

```
class CustomException < StandardError
  def initialize(data)
    @data = data
  end
end
# => nil 
raise CustomException.new(bla: "blupp")
# CustomException: CustomException
```

Comment: I've been using this for a year now, and thought I'd add: now every time I want to do this and forget how, I take a peek at [cancan's exceptions](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/blob/master/lib/cancan/exceptions.rb) to remind myself. The last error follows very good form for more complicated exceptions.

Comment: @vladCovaliov why would it fail? message is just empty

Comment: You should always add `message = nil` as your first arguments and call `super(message)` otherwise something like `raise CustomError, :some_message` will not set the message correctly.

Comment: How do you get the value of bla? (assume you rescued the exception, e):  would `e.bla` work?

Comment: the exception is just a plain ruby class. in order to get the value for `:bla` you would need to have a getter for `@data` and then access the hash key.

Comment: Where is the best place to put this?  `/lib/errors.rb` or somewhere in `/app` ?

Comment: @Jonathan there is no best place for this. it depends on where and how you use that class. it's also perfectly valid to declare it alongside orwithin another class or namespace.

Answer (score 9):

Here is a sample code adding a code to an error:

```rb
class MyCustomError < StandardError
    attr_reader :code

    def initialize(code)
        @code = code
    end

    def to_s
        "[#{code}] #{super}"
    end
end
```

And to raise it:
`raise MyCustomError.new(code), message`

Answer (score 8):

TL;DR 7 years after this question, I believe the correct answer is:

```rb
class CustomException < StandardError
  attr_reader :extra
  def initialize(message=nil, extra: nil)
    super(message)
    @extra = extra
  end
end
# => nil 
raise CustomException.new('some message', extra: "blupp")
```

WARNING: you will get identical results with:

```
raise CustomException.new(extra: 'blupp'), 'some message'
```

but that is because `Exception#exception(string)` does a `#rb_obj_clone` on `self`, and then calls `exc_initialize` (which does NOT call `CustomException#initialize`.  From [error.c](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/error.c#L956):

```c
static VALUE
exc_exception(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE self)
{
    VALUE exc;

    if (argc == 0) return self;
    if (argc == 1 && self == argv[0]) return self;
    exc = rb_obj_clone(self);
    exc_initialize(argc, argv, exc);

    return exc;
}
```

In the latter example of `#raise` up above, a `CustomException` will be `raise`d with `message` set to "a message" and `extra` set to "blupp" (because it is a clone) but *TWO* `CustomException` objects are actually created: the first by `CustomException.new`, and the second by `#raise` calling `#exception` on the first instance of `CustomException` which creates a second cloned `CustomException`.

My extended dance remix version of *why* is at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56371923/5299483

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple pattern for custom errors with additional information

If the extra information you're looking to pass is simply a type with a message, this works well:

```rb
# define custom error class
class MyCustomError < StandardError; end

# raise error with extra information
raise MyCustomError, 'Extra Information'
```

The result (in IRB):

```rb
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from (irb):22
        1: from (irb):22:in `rescue in irb_binding'
MyCustomError (Extra Information)
```

#### Example in a class

The pattern below has become exceptionally useful for me (pun intended). It's clean, can be easily modularized, and the errors are expressive. Within my class I define new errors that inherit from `StandardError`, and I raise them with messages (for example, the object associated with the error).

Here's a simple example, similar to OP's original question, that raises a custom error within a class and captures the method name in the error message:

```rb
class MyUser
  # class errors
  class MyUserInitializationError < StandardError; end

  # instance methods
  def simulate_failure
    raise MyUserInitializationError, "method failed: #{__method__}"
  end
end

# example usage: 
MyUser.new.simulate_failure

# => MyUser::MyUserInitializationError (method failed: simulate_failure)
```

Answer (score -1):

It's counterintuitive for programmers coming from e.g. Java, but the most effective way to do this is not to write a custom initializer, but rather to  write your own replacement for the [`Exception::exception` class method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.4/Exception.html#method-c-exception).

Per the [`Kernel#raise`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.4/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) docs:

> the first parameter should be an Exception class (**or another object that returns an `Exception` object when sent an `exception` message**). *[Emphasis added.]*

```rb
class MyException < StandardError

  class << self
    def exception(arg)
      # per `Exception::exception` docs
      return self if arg.nil? || self.equal?(arg)
      return MyException.new(arg.to_s) unless arg.is_a?(MyModel)

      # $! is a magic global variable holding the last raised
      # exception; Kernel#raise will also inject it as the 
      # cause attribute of the exception we construct here
      error_caught = $!
      msg = custom_message_for(arg, error_caught)

      ex = MyException.new(msg)
      # … any additional initialization goes here
      ex
    end

    private

    def custom_message_for(my_model_instance, error_caught)
      # …
    end
  end
end
```

This way, you can raise your custom exception normally, with a model instance instead of a string message, without having to remember to call `new` explicitly [and upset RuboCop](https://github.com/rubocop/ruby-style-guide#exception-class-messages), as well as confusing Ruby programmers that come to your code later expecting the standard syntax.

```rb
begin
  my_model.frob
rescue => e
  raise MyException, my_model # works
end

raise MyException, 'some other reason' # also works
```

The message & initialization logic from `MyException#exception` could also go in a custom initializer, letting you just write `MyException.new(arg, $!)`, but in that case make sure the initializer is smart enough to also handle a plain string message, and make sure it at some point calls `super` with a string message.

Answer (score -2):

You can create an new instance of your `Exception` subclass, then raise that. For instance:

```
begin
  # do something
rescue => e
  error = MyException.new(e, 'some info')
  raise error
end
```

Comment: You should be extending StandardError class - not Exception class. See here: http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/ruby-exceptions-and-exception-handling/