# How to include Custom exception in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't understand well how Rails include (or not?) some file from the app directory.

For example, I've created a new directory app/exceptions for create my own exceptions. Now, from a helpers file, I want to raise one of my exception.

Am I suppose to include something in this helper?

**The Helper: helpers/communications_helper.rb**

```
//should I include something or it's suppose to be autoloaded?
module CommunicationsHelper
 begin.
 .
 . 
 .
  raise ParamsException, "My exception is lauch!"
 rescue StandardError => e
...
 end
end
```

**The exception: exceptions/params_exception.rb**

```
class ParamsException < StandardError
  def initialize(object, operation)
    puts "Dans paramsException"
  end

end
```

Nothing specific from my raise in the output...

Thanks!

EDIT:
Thanks to all, your two answers was helpful in different way.
I didn't raise well the exception like you said, but I've also forggot to update my config.rb.
 so now I 've:

```
rescue StandardError => e
  raise ParamsError.new("truc", "truc")
```

Other question, do you know where can I catch the raise?
Cause I'm already in a catch block, so I'm little lost...

Comment: I would suggest to create a separate controller, and route errors to it. It would look simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I think that you're raising your exception incorrectly.

In your custom exception class, your initialize method takes in arguments. Therefore you should raise it with:

```
raise CustomError.new(arg1, arg2, etc.)
```

[Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11636874/raise-custom-exception-with-arguments).

Lastly, don't rescue from StandardError if CustomError is a child of StandardError; otherwise your manual 'raise' will be rescued.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't see output from your `raise`, make sure you're not rescuing the error by accident, since your error is a subclass of `StandardError`:

```
begin
  raise ParamsException, "My exception is lauch!"
rescue StandardError => e # This also rescues ParamsException
end
```

As a side note, in Ruby it's common practice to have your custom errors end with `Error` rather than `Exception`. Unlike some other programming languages, classes ending with `Exception` are meant for system level errors.

Comment: Rails should auto-load everything from `app` subdirectories

Comment: I heard about that also, so you think I don't have to add the line config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/app/exceptions) ?

Comment: @JulienLeray I've also tested that just to verify. You indeed don't have to add subdirectories of `app` to the autoload path. If loading failed, you would definitely have seen a `LoadError`, since that one isn't rescued in your code.