# How do I modify the exception message in a rescue clause?

Tags: ruby, exception

In the following, iteration over `['a', nil, 'c']` will fail at `nil` since you cannot do `nil + 'd'`. I would like to rescue that message, modify it, and pass it on to another method that stores the error.

```
number = 0
begin
  ['a', nil, 'c'].each_with_index do |entry, i|
    entry + 'd'
    number = i
  end
rescue => e
  e.message="#{e.message} (happened at entry: #{number})"
  store_exception(e)
end
```

The problem is, the method `message=` does not exists. How do I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add information to an exception message in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823748/how-do-i-add-information-to-an-exception-message-in-ruby)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer based on @fl00r answer, but slightly more 'fancy':

```
class ProxyException < BasicObject
  def initialize(exception, message=nil)
    @exception, @message = exception, message
  end

  def message
    @message || @exception.message
  end

  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    @exception.public_send(method_name, *args, &block)
  end
end
```

Then simply:

```
number = 0
begin
  ['a', nil, 'c'].each_with_index do |entry, i|
    entry + 'd'
    number = i
  end
rescue => e
  e = ProxyException.new e, "#{e.message} (happened at entry: #{number})"
  store_exception(e)
end
```

ProxyException is completely invisible as it delegates all the methods, including `class` and `object_id` to the exception object and hence it retain exception class and backtrace.

Answer (score 3):

You could create your custom Exception and use it as a proxy object

```
class ProxyException < StandardError; end

number = 0
begin
  ['a', nil, 'c'].each_with_index do |entry, i|
    entry + 'd'
    number = i
  end
rescue => e
  e = ProxyException.new "#{e.message} (happened at entry: #{number})"
  store_exception(e)
end
```

Comment: The only problem here is that it changes class of the exception as well.

Comment: @BroiSatse does OP want original Exception class?

Comment: @fl004 - It is not stated in the question. However since wants to modify exception message instead of just logging it modified version it would suggest that store_exception method is doing sth more complicated with an exception. Using ProxyException will also modify the backtrace.

Comment: @BroiSatse It is easy to see the class of `e` and create an execption or that class. And, unlike messages, backtrace can be modified; it is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you should not use exceptions for EXPECTED circumstances (ask yourself: Will my code work if I remove all exception handling code?). This is an expected circumstance which you can easily avoid by calling compact before passing the array to `each_with_index`:

```
['a', nil, 'c'].compact #=> ["a", "c"]
```

Comment: Mixed feelings about this answer - it might not be expected behaviour at all, all OP asked for is a way for better logging message from the exception. Your answer might be correct on how to fix this issue, but the issue itself could be just an example and hence you are not targeting the question itself.